# sharepoint 2010 create folder sandbox

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sandbox

I am using sharepoint 2010 sandbox solution and creating Document Library folder or uploading document in ListItemEveventReceiver on ItemAdded event. But when i call `folder.Update()` exception appears with message "The sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request". When i remove item from library in event handler it's ok. Also i tried create proxy operation(`SPProxyOperation`) but the same result appeared. I tried fix it with this post http://www.pdfsharepoint.com/error-sandboxed-too-busy-handle-request/. Here is the code:

`public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            var list = properties.List;
            if (list.Title.Equals("Learning Objects") 
                && properties.ListItem.File != null)
            {
                _publisher.PublishFile(properties.ListItem.File, list);
                var fileName = properties.ListItem.File.Name;
                if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(".zip"))
                {
                    var folder = list.Folders.Add(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                                  SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                                                  fileName);
                    folder.Update();`

```
                //some code
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks, Yauheni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yauheni, The link you provided is giving a solution for a problem occurring at the time of Solution activation in solution gallery. But according to your question, it is not the case with your code.

Since the code snippet you provided is prone to fire the 'ItemAdded' event continuously, you may try the following

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{ 
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    EventFiringEnabled = false;

    // your code goes here

    EventFiringEnabled = true;
}
```